# How to smoothen out a pit in a curved surface

Tags: mesh

**TL;DR: What is the best way to make the selected part in the image an as smooth as possible extension of the surrounding curved surface?**

I've been searching extensively the past hour, but cannot find the Q&A that I am looking for. I am trying to smoothen out pits in a curved surface. This is my mesh:

[image: The mesh with the pit still in there]

I have been asked to create a snap fitting for an airpod from this 3D scan. To do so, I am gonna subtract the shape of the airpod out of a bigger block. But to to that, I need a smooth surface to start with. I can not make a snap fit from an airpod with pits (you wouldn't be able to press the airpod in the snap fit).

I tried doing a limited dissolve, after which I deleted all the surfaces that were part of the pit. The hole that is created this way I tried to fill with the **Fill** and **Grid fill** functions, but this either gave non smooth or irregular surfaces.

Comment: For editing 3D scan data I'd recommend using MeshLab. Remove the problematic areas in Blender, export it for instance as .ply and open the mesh in MeshLab. Use *Filter > Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction > Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction* to fix the mesh. Export the mesh labeled *Poisson Mesh*.

Comment: Thanks mate, I was looking for a quick fix and did it with sculpting for now. My client didn't have any time to lose and I had no time to install MeshLab, I will definately remember this for next time.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the *Cast modifier*.

1. Select the area you want to 'smoothen' and add it to a *vertex group* (I named it *ball part*)
2. Add a *Cast modifier* set to *Sphere* and limited to the vertex group.
3. Use the *Factor, Radius and Size* sliders to correct the shape.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :). But I ended up using the sculpt tool, the result did not have to be super accurate so even with no experience at all I kinda managed to do it that way. Only after I was finished I read your comment :(

Comment: You're right, sculpt tool is a very good solution :). Good luck with your project.